# Why have I been question banned?

Tags: support, post-ban

Today I went to ask a question about navigation bars, and found I was question banned. I only have 1 negatively received post (out of 4), and I deleted it once I was told why it wasn't suitable, and have never said anything rude/offensive/etc. I have 97 reputation.

I have only been emailed by a moderator once, and it was for making too small of edits (as I was going around and when I saw questions with bad grammar I fixed them- I assumed this was wanted because the EXAMPLE edit description put in is "Fixed grammar").

I also have no negatively received answers (excluding a SINGLE one that only got one downvote, and it was on the same question that I got received poorly on- it was a self answer).

Why was I question banned? I mean, I plan to go around and try to put good answers as to get myself unbanned, but I would like to know what it was so it won't happen again.

Comment: You say you’ve deleted one question. Deleted questions still count against you, and if there’s earlier poorly-received ones that have also been deleted, that could be the cause. If you can somehow resurrect the question you deleted and edit it to be a good question, it would benefit you to do so. If your other questions can be improved, it would be wise to do so as well.

Comment: I have no deleted other questions. And I cannot improve the other question. It was incredibly broad... It was basically a full guide on HTTP servers. So no way I can fix it. My other questions are just simply minor, and even if I make them perfect I can't get more upvotes on them as they just won't been seen or cared about.

Comment: @Makoto I don't think my questions qualify as "extremely poor". Also, the question DOESN'T go against me because I forgot to delete it until over 30 days after it was closed, so it does not count against me.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that the question doesn't "go against you" because you didn't delete it for more than 30 days.

Comment: Where did you see that? Because it seems it is not correct, as we can see here.

Comment: "Are deleted posts taken into account too?"

Comment: I suspect that information might need some tweaking. It references a very old post from Jeff, and I think it's more complex than that, now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 7 questions on your account, only two of which are not deleted. Of the five deleted, the scores are 0, 0, -1, -2, -4.

You are basically correct about your answers, but that's not as relevant for a question ban. For your perusal, your three negatively-scored, deleted questions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109277/batch-variable-issues
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726458/server-re-reading-network-stream
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259348/how-to-make-an-http-web-server-guide

Comment: I actually just deleted the 2 0s. I didn't even realize I had the other questions. I guess that explains it :/

Comment: Actually though, why WOULD those count? "Yes, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) and deleted answers count towards an automatic ban." meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/…

Comment: @Zeu, what? You deleted two of those three questions (the third is the one where you promised never, ever to ask a question again on Stack Overflow) less than an hour after you posted them.

Comment: I mean I recently deleted the 2 0s, and I forgot about the other questions.